# Which episode of "Space: Above and Beyond" starts with a broken heart quote?

Tags: episode-identification, space-above-and-beyond

Very similar to my [second question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/269919/7885).

I recall that one of the middle episodes of ["Space: Above and Beyond" (1995–1996)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112173/?ref_=ttqt_qt_tt) starts with the quote similar to this one:

> It is year 21XX. We can cure every disease except for a broken heart

Which exactly episode it is and what is the exact text of that phrase?

I was more than sure that it will be either [S1.E15 "The Angriest Angel"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0706374/?ref_=ttep_ep15) or [S1.E14 "Never No More"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0706366/?ref_=ttep_ep14).

Mostly because these two episodes are episode arc about dealing with one of the alien invaders imposing "baron" Manfred von Richthofen (and his famous ship). And the killing of one of the male crew members (I have forgotten his stage name) in a duel with that alien, which made a "heart rip" to another crew member caused the narrator to say these words.

But then it turned out that [Quotes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112173/quotes/?ref_=tt_trv_qu) has nothing about "heart" or "broken".