# Which episode of "Space: Above and Beyond" has the famous regulators quote?

Tags: episode-identification, space-above-and-beyond

Very similar to my [previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/269918/7885).

I recall that one of the episodes of ["Space: Above and Beyond" (1995–1996)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112173/?ref_=ttqt_qt_tt) includes quote similar to this one:

> -- The Regulator...
>
> -- Yes?
>
> -- Who controls the birds?
>
> --  I do... I control the birds!
>
> -- Who controls you?

Which exactly episode it is and what is the exact text of that phrase?

I have browsed [Quotes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112173/quotes/?ref_=tt_trv_qu), but found nothing about "bird" or "regulator".

Comment: *Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be *Who Monitors the Birds?*, except it used the word Monitor, not regulator- the dialogue you heard in question was in the indoctrination scene where Hawkes asks a monitor "who monitors the birds?" When the monitor says "I do" Hawkes asks, "Who monitors you?".

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is an adaptation of a [passage from Juvenal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F). The scene would probably be a nice addition to the Wikipedia page.